# Modifying Polymer's sampler-scaffold to load custom elements instead of iframes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, polymer, web-component

i love the look and transitions of Google Polymer's `<sampler-scaffold>`

you can see it in action here on polymers site: [sampler-scaffold](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/demo.html#paper-checkbox)

I want to use it for is a single page app (SPA) and would like to load my custom elements into the scaffold instead of loading extraneous iframes that have no connection to my SPA model.

The actual swap happens here in their code:

```
frameLoaded: function() {
    if (!this.item) {
      return;
    }
    this.$.frame.contentWindow.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
      setTimeout(this.updateFrameHeight.bind(this), 100);
      this.$.frame.contentWindow.addEventListener('core-resize',
        this.boundResizeFrame, false);
    }.bind(this));
  },
```

and the DOM object that is manipulated:

```
<!-- main content -->
<div id="frameContainer">
    <iframe id="frame" on-load="{{frameLoaded}}"></iframe>
</div><!-- End main content -->
```

What i tried to do was replace the iframe element with a content element and load my custom elements into the content tag, but the page simply dosn't load the main panel that slides up and no errors are logged. Additionally, there are a few helper functions that adjust the frame height after the iframe has loaded. You can see their source code here for `<sampler-scaffold>`:

[sampler scaffold source](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/sampler-scaffold/sampler-scaffold.html)

Has anyone modded the `<sampler-scaffold>` away from loading iframes?

if not - can i still achieve a data heavy application with polymer's `<sampler-scaffold>` element and iframes?

I am afraid that loading iframes instead of pages/elements will just give me headaches when i try to connect to my DBs and send real time statistics via HTTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<!-- main content -->
<div id="frameContainer">
<content select=".testpage" fit></content>
</div><!-- End main content -->
```

JS

```
  ready: function() {
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', this.parseLocationHash.bind(this));
  },

  domReady: function() {
    this.async(function() {
      this.parseLocationHash();
    }, null, 300);
  },

  parseLocationHash: function() {
    var route = window.location.hash.slice(1);
    for (var i = 0, item; item = this.$.menu.items[i]; i++) {
      if (item.getAttribute('tag') === route) {
        this.$.menu.selected = i;
        return;
      }
    }
    this.$.menu.selected = this.$.menu.selected || 0;
  },

  menuSelect: function(e, detail) {
    if (detail.isSelected) {
      this.item = detail.item;
      if (this.item.children.length) {
        this.item.selected = 0;
      }

      this.item.tag = this.item.getAttribute('tag');
      var url = this.item.getAttribute('url');
      window.location.hash = this.item.tag;

      if (this.narrow) {
        this.$.drawerPanel.closeDrawer();
      } else {
        this.animateCard();
      }
    }
  },

  animateCard: function() {
    this.$.card.classList.remove('move-up');
    this.$.card.style.display = 'none';
    this.async(function() {
      this.$.card.style.display = 'block';
      this.moveCard(this.$.mainHeaderPanel.offsetHeight);
      this.async(function() {
        this.$.card.classList.add('move-up');
        this.moveCard(null);
      }, null, 300);
    });
  },

  moveCard: function(y) {
    var s = this.$.card.style;
    s.webkitTransform = s.transform = 
        y ? 'translate3d(0, ' + y + 'px,0)' : '';
  },

  cardTransitionDone: function() {
    if (this.$.card.classList.contains('move-up')) {
      this.$.card.classList.remove('move-up');
    }
  },

  togglePanel: function() {
    this.$.drawerPanel.togglePanel();
  },
```

index.html

```
<custom-element class="testpage"></custom-element>

      <div class="testpage" style="margin: 20px;"> Augue duis dolore te feugait nulla, facilisi nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option. Legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius claritas est. Exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex. Humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima eodem modo typi. Insitam est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum. Litterarum formas qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari fiant sollemnes in? Nostrud ea commodo consequat duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse?</div>
```

both the standard element and the custom element are now loaded instead of any external iframes.

Comment: Can you share bit more code? What goes inside sampler-scaffold tag, how to connect the specific menu item to load some custom element?

Comment: polymer turned out to be way too BETA for our apps - we decided to go with http://onsen.io/ for a front-end mobile orientated framework

Comment: @Dan Do you have a working sample of the modified sampler-scaffold? How does the switch between multiple pages works?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. But I do know a really good tutorial for SPA. Just check out [this article](https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/spa.html) on the polymer-project website!

Have fun :)!